# How to put notes/reminder on the Lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

I want create a app to save the notes, reminders, daily task and want to display these on the **`Lockscreen`** and when user tap the note, app will open and display the task on its screen with **Customised view and background**. I've done a lot of search about how to do this but got no luck.

For reference

- [ScreenMemo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id1076142251?pt=1013317&ct=portfolio&mt=8), [Task Paper](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id591684341) and many more apps doing the same.

I've no Idea which library to use to achieve this. Please help and share your code/links for better understandability.

Thanks

Comment: You could try Apple Local Notification https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: Can I design my local notification as per my need? I mean the graphic that i want to display

Comment: Regarding custom UI design, there are few open source libraries available for apn, for instance https://github.com/avielg/AGPushNote

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to let your app display a Local Notification. Local notification pops up on the Lock screen with your desired text and clicking on it will open your App. You can as well configure which page to open the app if the notification is clicked.

Here is an example:

Step1:

```
import UIKit
```

Step2:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let notification = UILocalNotification()
if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
    notification.alertTitle = "Notification Title!"
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}

notification.alertBody = "This is the notification text"

notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)

notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1

notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

//showinitial = false

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Can you please demonstrate with some example. how to customise the view for `Local Notification`

Comment: But this will not customise the view. How can I replace the default display View with my custom view

Comment: Hope you got what I'm saying. See the application for reference, they have custom view if they are using  Local Notification

Comment: yes I understood, you want your custom view. Unfortunately Apple allow only to use the default Notifications so I guess you have no choice but using the native one.

Comment: But some application using the customised view, How they are doing that? :(

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but i want something different :)